# ffmpeg - alternative to AVCodecContext::refcounted_frames?

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg

We are using an outdated version of AVCodec which does not contain the ref-counted frames feature implemented via [`AVCodecContext::refcounted_frames`](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVCodecContext.html#ab16d1e0c729a7b63d918d5ec027ba064). Basically, we want to prevent AVCodec from re-using a buffer until we are done with it, which could be at any arbitrary point in the future (and not necessarily before the next `avcodec_decode_frame2`).

Using a different `AVFrame` on each call to decode doesn't do the trick, because AVCodec uses the same buffers internally anyway (different `AVFrames` may point to the same data).

Is there a way to do this without using the new features introduced with `AVCodecContext::refcounted_frames`?

Comment: Are you using "av_frame_unref"?

Comment: That's exactly the feature that I can't use. :) It was added in the following commits: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/7ecc2d403ce5c7b6ea3b1f368dccefd105209c7e ; https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/759001c534287a96dc96d1e274665feb7059145d ; our version predates that.